# Selenium Attribute Error in firefox61.01 64 Bit (python 3.6 - 32bit)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can someone help. My program basically does everything right up until it has a problem with the assigned to field. I don't see an issue with the code. The exact same field type assigned group, populated with the code written.

Why does it have an issue with this field?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

base_url =  "https://xxxxservice-now.com/login.do"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)



# INC CREATE WITH SAVE AND STAY

driver.get(base_url)
username = driver.find_element_by_id("user_name")
username.send_keys("admin")

time.sleep(1)


password = driver.find_element_by_id("user_password")
password.send_keys("xxxx")

time.sleep(1)

loginBtn = driver.find_element_by_id("sysverb_login")
loginBtn.click()

time.sleep(1)
#driver.implicitly_wait(5)

#driver.switch_to_frame("gsft_main")
createnew = driver.find_element_by_id("filter")
createnew.send_keys("Create New")
time.sleep(3)
createnew.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.switch_to_frame("gsft_main")


category = driver.find_element_by_name("incident.category")
#category = driver.find_element_by_id("incident.category")
category.send_keys("Software")
time.sleep(2)

subcategory = driver.find_element_by_id("incident.subcategory")
subcategory.send_keys("Email")
time.sleep(1)

time.sleep(2)
callerbox = driver.find_element_by_id("sys_display.incident.caller_id")
callerbox.send_keys("Abraham Lincoln")
callerbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(1)

contacttype = driver.find_element_by_id("incident.contact_type")
contacttype.send_keys("Email")
time.sleep(1)

impact = driver.find_element_by_id("incident.impact")
impact.send_keys("2")
time.sleep(1)

urgency = driver.find_element_by_id("incident.urgency")
urgency.send_keys("2")
time.sleep(1)

assign_grp = driver.find_element_by_id("sys_display.incident.assignment_group")
assign_grp.send_keys("Database")

#assign_grp.click()
time.sleep(1)

short_desc = driver.find_element_by_id("incident.short_description")
short_desc.send_keys("This is an automated test!!")
time.sleep(1)

desc = driver.find_element_by_id("incident.description")
desc.send_keys("Here are some notes")
time.sleep(1)

#driver.find_element_by_id("sysverb_update_and_stay").click() 
#driver.find_element_by_id("sysverb_insert").click()

button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/span/span/nav/div/div[1]/button[2]')
button.click()
save_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div[2]')
save_btn.click()
#button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#time.sleep(3)


select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("incident.state"))
select.select_by_visible_text("In Progress")
time.sleep(1)

assigned_to = driver.find.element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sys_display.incident.assigned_to"]')
assigned_to.send_keys("Beth Anglin")
time.sleep(1)
"""
assigned_to = driver.find.element_by_name("sys_display.incident.assigned_to")
assigned_to.send_keys("Beth Anglin")
time.sleep(1)
"""

time.sleep(1)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/span/span/nav/div/div[1]/button[2]')
button.click()
button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Output -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hassy/Google Drive/Selenium/firefox_Inc_Create_Save_Stay.py", line 100, in <module>
    assigned_to = driver.find.element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sys_display.incident.assigned_to"]')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a typo in cod

instead of this: (dot after find)

```
assigned_to = driver.find.element_by_name("sys_display.incident.assigned_to")
```

it should be:( underscore)

```
assigned_to = driver.find_element_by_name("sys_display.incident.assigned_to")
```

Comment: I think you are correct I was missing the underscore between find and element

Comment: @anfield : Accept this answer, if this was helpful to you. (By clicking on check mark which is just under the down vote button)

Answer (score 0):

The method name(i.e. `find.element`) is not correct. Try following:

```
assigned_to = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sys_display.incident.assigned_to"]')
assigned_to.send_keys("Beth Anglin")
```